# How to access a SQL CE database file (sdf) from python (with pyodbc)

Tags: python, pyodbc, sdf

I am on Win10 and python 3.11. Trying to access/read a Compact SQL sdf file with the following script:

```
import pyodbc 
connstr = 'Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=RecipeDatabase.sdf;'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
```

Unfortunately I am getting:

```
Exception has occurred: InterfaceError
('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
  File "C:\Users\clw\source\repos\SQLCEDatenbankTest.py", line 23, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The sdf file is in the same folder as the script.

What is the correct connectionstring syntax to access the sdf file?

Note: I tried to access with adodbapi, but adodbapi seems to require Python >= 3.9

Comment: pyodbc is a package for working with ODBC connections. You are trying to use an ADODB connection. AFAIK, there has never been a way to connect to a SQL Server Compact Edition database via ODBC.